# How to Retrieve the value Mode

Tags: r

The goal is to retrieve a mode based on the column and its data.

```
data <- data.frame(test=c("a","b","c","a","a","a","a","c","c","c","c","c","c"))
```

Is there an R built-in function or standard way to calculate the mode of `data$test`?

Comment: How is the mode of a list of characters defined?

Comment: @user3969377 The value occurring the most, is it not?

Comment: user3969377 - Yes it is.

Comment: "How is the mode of a list of characters defined? " I don't understand your question.

Comment: Can you just use names(sort(-table(data$test))[1])

Comment: Here's another [option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982938/how-to-find-the-most-frequent-values-across-several-columns-containing-factors)

Answer (score 2):

```
table(data$test)

#a b c 
#5 1 7 


table(data$test)==max(table(data$test))

#    a     b     c 
#FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

or

```
names(table(data$tes)[table(data$test)==max(table(data$test))])
#[1] "c"
```

Comment: I don't understand. What does "max(table(data$test))" do?

Comment: @FullMetalGame it's the number of times the mode occurs which in this case is 7

Comment: @RichardScriven - `which.max()` does not handle solutions where there are multiple modes, which is not an issue here - but could very well be the case in other datasets.