# Get the most frequent value per row and account for ties

Tags: r, count, recode

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = 1:6, 
                 "Group1" = c("A", NA, "C", NA, "E", "C"), 
                 "Group2" = c("E", "C", "C", NA, "E", "E"),
                 "Group3" = c("A", "A", NA, NA, "C", NA),
                 "Group4" = c(NA, "C", NA, "D", "C", NA),
                 "Group5" = c("A", "D", NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

In each row, I want to count the number of each value and store the most frequent value in a new variable, `New.Group`. In case of ties, the first value in the row should be selected. The logic applied to the example:

Row 1 of `New.Group` takes value `A` because it is most frequent value in the row, ignoring `NA`s.

Row 2 takes value `C` because it is also the most frequent value.

Row 3 the same as Row 2.

Row 4 takes value `D` because it's the only value in the row.

In Row 5 both `E` and `C` has count 2, but `E` is selected because it is encountered before `C` in the row.

Row 6, similar to row 5, both `C` and `E` has count 1, but `C` is selected because it is encountered before `E` in the row.

The desired output:

```
  ID Group1 Group2 Group3 Group4 Group5 New.Group
1  1      A      E      A   <NA>      A         A
2  2   <NA>      C      A      C      D         C
3  3      C      C   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>         C
4  4   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>      D   <NA>         D
5  5      E      E      C      C   <NA>         E
6  6      C      E   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>         C
```

Comment: How exactly are the column priorities defined?

Comment: first column is more important than second, second than third and so on.

Comment: Related, but doesn't seem to handle the "_In case of ties, select the first value_": [Find the most frequent value by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982938/find-the-most-frequent-value-by-row)

Comment: @Henrik For one of our internal packages I've made `rowMode`-function in which you can set what the function should do with ties and missing values. [Posted it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63100111/2204410).

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @Jaap. Nice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this achieves what you're looking for. For each row, it creates a table of frequencies of each letter and chooses the largest, whilst preserving column order for ties. It then returns the name of the first column in this table.

Thanks to Henrik for suggesting the improvement.

```r
df$New.Group <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) {
names(which.max(table(factor(x, unique(x)))))
})

df
#>   ID Group1 Group2 Group3 Group4 Group5 New.Group
#> 1  1      A      E      A   <NA>      A         A
#> 2  2   <NA>      C      A      C      D         C
#> 3  3      C      C   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>         C
#> 4  4   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>      D   <NA>         D
#> 5  5      E      E      C      C   <NA>         E
#> 6  6      C      E   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>         C
```

Comment: @Henrik yes, that's better. I thought I had tried that and rejected it for some reason, but I think it's logically the same (and neater). Thank you.

Comment: and it does account for ties

Answer (score 3):

One option using `dplyr` and `vctrs` (utilizing the `location` parameter in `vec_count()` which "orders by location where key first seen") could be:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(New.Group = na.omit(vec_count(c_across(starts_with("Group")), "location")) %>%
         slice_max(count, with_ties = FALSE) %>%
         pull(key))

     ID Group1 Group2 Group3 Group4 Group5 New.Group
  <int> <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct>    
1     1 A      E      A      <NA>   A      A        
2     2 <NA>   C      A      C      D      C        
3     3 C      C      <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   C        
4     4 <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   D      <NA>   D        
5     5 E      E      C      C      <NA>   E        
6     6 C      E      <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   C
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(New.Group = names(which.max(with(na.omit(vec_count(c_across(starts_with("Group")), "location")), setNames(count, key)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the `Mode` function

```
Mode <- function(x) {
   ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
 }

df$New.Group <- apply(df[-1], 1, FUN = function(x) Mode(na.omit(x)))
df$New.Group
#[1] "A" "C" "C" "D" "E" "C"
```